# How To Run Postman Collection Again, Passing A Different Value Into Environment Variable?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have some Postman tests to run.

The majority of them are GET requests, with the following URL:

```
{{BASE_URI}}/api/controlli-formali/controlla-dominio-dati/2020/1?stato_controllo_attivo=1.
```

I wanted to know if it is possible, and in which way eventually, to assign the path parameter "stato_controllo_attivo" to an environment variable, and run the same tests/requests I automatically run earlier without changing the environment variable manually, but letting it increase by 1 for each iteration of the tests, until `stato_controllo_attivo < 4`.

So far I have no idea how to manage this, so unluckily I'm at zero progress made by now.

Comment: Define parameter value into json file, provide that file to the Postman runner and set iteration for the request.